# Как задать права для процессов nodejs,pm2,nextjs?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, файловая-система

Процессы nodejs, pm2, nextjs создают на сервере с DebianOS файлы с owner root, как переключить их на только www-data?

Comment: так запускайте их от имени нужного пользователя.

Comment: ^ помогло, создал огр пользователя им запустил

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Для PM2 в [инструкции по установке](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/startup-hook/#installation) указанно, что можно [указать пользователя](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/startup-hook/#user-permissions), от которого будет работать процесс

```
pm2 startup ... --user www-data ...
```